# signing soap attachment content only in Python

Tags: python, soap-client, mime, binary-data, mime-message

I have been trying to sign a soap attachment in the request in python and lately, I have managed to modify the code of signxml to reference the CID and build the reference node accordingly. Any yet, the server has not been able to verify the signatures and looking to see whether anyone has any experience in troubleshooting this?

Below is the code to attach the gzip file as a MIME attachment and send as binary with no transformation:

```
            input = open(self._attachment_file, 'rb').read()
            gzipped_content = open(self._attachment_gzipped_temp, 'rb').read()

            # store attachment content
            document = MIMEApplication(_data=gzipped_content,
                                       _subtype='gzip',
                                       _encoder=encode_base64)

            # decompressed the payload to validate the content
            a = document.get_payload().encode('utf-8')
            b = base64.b64decode(a)
            decompressed = gzip.decompress(b)
            if list(decompressed) == list(input):
                logger.info("decompressed content matches input")
            else:
                logger.info("MIME content decompressed unsuccessfully")

            self._attachment_content = gzipped_content
            self._attachment_reference_dict["content"] = self._attachment_content
            _final_attachment_reference_list = self.attachment_reference_list

            del (document['mime-version'])
            del (document['Content-Transfer-Encoding'])
            document.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64')
            document.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='Part1')
            document.add_header('Content-ID', '<' + self._attachment_id + '>')
```

from there, the `self._attachment_content` is input directly as pre-digest input before digesting with no canonicalization / transform (since the content is in binary already?) and then the signature reference node is computed successfully from the signxml library, leading us to the below output:

```
--==================MTOM==================
Content-Type: application/gzip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Part1"
Content-ID: <attachment1>
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=

--==================MTOM==================--
```

and the signed part in the soap request message being:

```
<ds:Reference URI="cid:attachment1">
      <ds:Transforms>
       <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-SwAProfile-1.1#Attachment-Content-Signature-Transform"/>
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <ds:DigestValue>ZjefgSY2UDbrq/tH8JyWZgXd6X17sj6+n2k+yz/MPmY=</ds:DigestValue>
     </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>gCC5VQrp9SBc66K5E/LlaKoCb/q1IiS2vzfa+GwUFfI+VtVI6FtGqLb6gAdPOy1P0uj6qfKJ0PxMXFAzegRHP5HD8HA1/pVFLQkgrWKcfKi4FyBxalE5vsBqBqyK/C8pVMiq5Cya76MZ40znl43JO1l0xziCOMEAPfl96PMUHu1NiWx6kx7x9C3nOL//KJ+9YM630BIIz6HI5BEcEcJbI6rdToiGmDzVKgXlBQ7N12P7aThntiKYj579kAMZRhqphd/gJxH6XMfN3akO3sPglcAKOPHcGKojQGBNwvmMS8gXMEa4jWUS22SI5xABFiwfE9bbf2PjbE9s5zW82YVIcg==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      <wsse:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#signingCert"/>
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="soapbody"/>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have put the pre-transfer-encoded (pre base64 in this case) content for the digesting as per the code.

Wondering anyone has the ideas about why this is leading to a signatures verification error? I can confirm the signing keys are all properly functioning as if only sign the XML nodes, the server returns a valid response. The issues really now is coming from the signed attachment.

Grateful for your help!

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? Seems like this is more or less the whole reference to this topic on the whole internet